# Select all swatches by stroke color name?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

First off I am using Illustrator CC 2017. I am attempting to programatically select objects based on their stroke color name. Below is my code thus far, it does not error, it simply does nothing. Any help would be appreciated!

```
function selectObjts() {    
var myDoc = app.activeDocument;  
var allItems = myDoc.pageItems;  
var toSelect = Array();  
for ( var i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++ ) {      
          if ( allItems[i].strokeColor == 'Artios_Cut' ) { toSelect.push( foo[i] ) };     
};  
myDoc.selection = toSelect;  
}
selectObjts()
```